# How to create a custom device driver for gobot

Tags: pi-3

I am relatively new for raspberry and gobot. I want to create a custom device driver for LDR. I want to use a LDR with gobot framework. I am confused here.

I referred [this](https://github.com/hybridgroup/gobot/blob/master/platforms/raspi/raspi_adaptor.go#L159) official documentation. But can't get an idea.

If someone can explain how its working or at least a good tutorial series it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to explain more clearly what you are referring to.  A device driver in a linux context is usually considered to be a kernel module, and those are written in C, but the documentation you reference is in Go.  It is possible to write a userspace driver in any language, although I think in this case the language ("device driver") is probably more of an obfuscation than anything.  Begging the question:  What is it *specifically* you want to write a program to do?  What is it you mean by "custom device driver"?

Comment: I want to use a LDR, currently gobot does not have a LDR driver.